# Can someone please provide the stotra of Manasa Devi in Sanskrit?

Tags: devi, stotra

Please provide the stotra of Manasa Devi in Sanskrit, along with a translation in English if possible?

Comment: Is [this](https://stotranidhi.com/en/sri-manasa-devi-stotram-mahendra-krutam-in-english/) the Stotram you are looking for or it's another one?

Comment: @Rickross- Yes its this one. Below I was provided the sanskrit text too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Sanskrit Documents](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/devii/), we can source some of the following works dedicated to Manasā Devī:

- [Sarpabhayanāśaka Manasāstotram: सर्पभयनाशक मनसास्तोत्रम्](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/manasAstotram.html)
  (Source yet to identified)

- [**Manasādevī Stotram: मनसादेवी स्तोत्रम्**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/manasAdevIstotramBVP.html)
  This is found in Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa: Prakṛti Khaṇḍa (Chapter 46: Verse 130).
  One can read the English translation from [here](https://ia800906.us.archive.org/9/items/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/357106438-Brahmavaivarta-Purana-1-Sanskrit-text-with-English-translation-pdf.pdf): (Page 468 of the PDF file or Page 407 of the scanned book)

- [Manasādevī Dvādaśanāmastotram: मनसादेवी द्वादशनामस्तोत्रम](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/manasAdvAdashanAmastotram.html) 
  (Source yet to be identified)

- [Manasā Chālīsā: मनसा चालीसा](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_otherlang_hindi/manasa40.html) 
  Like all the Chālīsās, this one too is a "modern work", not found in any canonical scriptures.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the one from the Brahmavaivarta Purana. I appreciate the stotra and the translation.